頃+ から? How does it differ from just 頃?
The character is pondering is good fortune and how couldn't imagine this development. So he says
なんかまだ夢みたいです。最初の頃からは想像つかないよなぁって。。。。
I'm aware of 頃は but what does 頃からは adds to it?

I'm almost sure that ななか should be なんだか...

This から does not mark temporal origin, but the sentence is based on the structure ～から想像がつく, and 最初の頃 here implies something like 最初の頃（の状況・様子）.

"から想像がつく"? What do you mean?

Sorry for my rough answer. から here is associated with 想像 in the phrase 想像がつく and marking basis/reason of the prediction/imagination/outlook.
